# Determinar o campo no ORDER BY RAND() no mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Determinar qual campo da tabela vai ter ORDER BY RAND()

Exemplo: mostrar os dados aleatório de acordo com o campo (id_categoria)

Como que eu coloco um: WHERE ORDER BY RAND() id_categoria ???

Comment: Não entendi. Não existe isso de rand de um campo, `RAND()` simplesmente vai gerar um número aleatório qualquer.

Comment: O problema é na sintaxe?

Comment: Sim! Tem como determinar um campo da tabela, quando for usar o ORDER BY RAND() ?

Comment: Qual é o resultado que você quer? Por que precisa randomizar o id de um campo? Usar qualquer número randômico para ordem não daria na mesma?

Comment: Para "mostrar os dados de forma aleatória", faça a consulta no banco sem `ORDER BY` e use a função [`shuffle()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) do PHP para randomizar o resultado. (Escrevo isso baseado na tag `php` da pergunta).

Comment: Seria legal explicar um pouco melhor o que você quer na pergunta. Talvez, explicar textualmente o que você quer que aconteça de fato nos resultados, em vez de explicar apenas a query que está tentando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos dizer que sua tabela tenha essa estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE `cliente` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=49 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

---

Ficaria a SQL assim, porque quero que ele só faça rand() na `id`

```
SELECT a.id, b.nome from (SELECT id FROM cliente ORDER BY rand()) a join cliente b on b.id = a.id
```

---

No seu caso (exemplo por desconhecer totalmente sua estrutura)

```
SELECT a.id_categoria, b.* FROM (SELECT id_categoria, a.id FROM tabela ORDER BY rand()) a join tabela b on b.id = a.id
```

Comment: Mas faz diferença deixar de usar a subquery e simplesmente usar ORDER BY RAND() na query de fora? Eu acho que não faz.

Comment: faz diferença acabei de realizar teste @bfavaretto

Comment: Qual diferença? Se for na ordem, cada execução vai dar uma ordem diferente, porque é rand.

Answer (score 6):

Segundo a [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) não é possível obter resultados aleatórios por uma determinada coluna.

> You cannot use a column with RAND() values in an ORDER BY clause,
> because ORDER BY would evaluate the column multiple times. However,
> you can retrieve rows in random order like this:
>
> `mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl_name ORDER BY RAND()`
>
> Você não pode usar uma coluna com valores RAND () em uma cláusula ORDER BY, pois ORDER BY avaliaria a coluna múltiplas vezes. No entanto, você pode recuperar linhas em ordem aleatória como esta:
>
> `mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl_name ORDER BY RAND()`

Comment: Só acrescentando: não só "não é possível", como diz a documentação, como não consigo ver por que seria *necessário* :)

Comment: Junto com um `limit` em uma `subquery` podemos extrair categorias aleatorias de uma outra tabela. Ex: `SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE categoria_id IN (SELECT categoria_id FROM categorias GROUP BY categoria_id ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5)`. Único case de uso que consegui imaginar :)

Comment: Com certeza é válido, mas queria ver um caso real pra isso :p